# What is the best way to transfer an object between two iOS devices running the same app?

Tags: iphone, file, ios, data-transfer, gamekit

I'm trying to give my iOS app the ability to transfer an object to another iOS device running the same app.  The object is on the order a few thousand KB of memory.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to do this?  I am considering using FTP, but that seems a little messy.  Does anyone have any suggestions on possibly using GameKit?  Or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GameKit would probably be your best bet. This [link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/07/01/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-game-kit-part-1/) seems to go over it pretty well

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I've found the SimpleNetworkStream example that apple gives an exact match as to what I want to do.  Simple Peer to Peer file transfer might be the best solution....  It seems that people are having a lot of trouble transferring large data objects with GameKit.