# how can i transfer a file from one iphone to another iphone/ipad device without using a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can anybody suggest me a method of how to send/share a file from one iphone/ipad device to another. Is it possible to achieve it using Bonjour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to transfer an object between two iOS devices running the same app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755195/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-an-object-between-two-ios-devices-running-the-sa)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GameKit API to send data between peers over a Bluetooth connection. GKSession has the following method :

```
- (void) mySendDataToPeers: (NSData *) data
{
    [session sendDataToAllPeers: data withDataMode: GKSendDataReliable error: nil];
}
```

Comment: You have to be aware that there is a limit to the size of data you can send in one "packet" with this.  So you might have to split your data up and reassemble it (in the correct order) on the other side.